# Use `[[` or `[` or a combination for testing a bash script?

Tags: bash, testing

Is it good to have in one bash script `[[` and `[` combined, depending on tests being used, or should one stick only with one of them for consistency?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have both available, `[[` is better (more consistent syntax, more comparison capabilities, etc) and there's no reason I can think of to use `[`. On the other hand, if you're writing a script that needs to be able to run under a generic POSIX-conpatible shell (i.e. you can't count on running under bash or zsh or whatever), then you *cannot* use `[[` and must make do with `[`.

Basically, if your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/zsh` or `#!/bin/ksh`, you can (and should) use `[[`. If it starts with `#!/bin/sh`, you *must* use `[` exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

A single bracket ([) usually actually calls a program named [; man test or man [ for more info. Example:

The double bracket ([[) does the same thing as a single bracket, but is a bash builtin.

more info you can see [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: I did not ask for a difference between the two.

Comment: `[` is a bash builtin, in addition to being a separate program. Type `type -a [` and `help [`